# Exporting data from Wikimapia into KML?

Tags: qgis, kml, wikimapia

I am trying to find all electrical substations within Germany and I have found that there is a category for that on Wikimapia under "electrical-substation". I have been able to display using this link here: https://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=51.371780&lon=12.502441&z=6&m=w&tag=16500&search=electric%20substation

I tried using this tutorial which uses Wikimapia API to download data as KML but every time I download the data it is downloading an empty KML file.

https://blog.cartong.org/2014/10/30/tutorial-using-wikimapia-data-in-qgis/

Is there a way I can download data through this API and view it in QGIS or is there any other solution?

Comment: This is from your second link and might be relevant “Be careful not to choose too large of an area, it is only possible to download 100 objects at a time. If you want to cover a large area, divide it into multiple queries.”

Comment: @fatih_dur i am currently downloading only 100 objects. i also tried with smaller area but the result is same